# What is difference between binary and source file?

Tags: software-installation, source-code, binary

I want to install special software on Ubuntu. In its installation guide has been mentioned I must separate binary and source files from each other.
What does it mean?
How can I do that?

Should I ignore the point of instruction about separating binary and source files?
I downloaded git source of special software from Internet. It is a zip file that consists of 9 folders (“cmake”, “CMakefiles”, “docs”, “gui”, “modellingframework”, “optimisation”, “otbsuppl”, “QtpropertyBrowser” and “shared”) and 6 files (“Cmakelist.txt”, “GPLV3.txt”, “INSTALL”, “LICENSE”, “LUMASSConfig.h.in” and “README”). I didn't understand what they are?
Sorry, I'm very unfamiliar with Linux and Ubuntu.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve? Which software do you want to install? Do you have a link for us so we can inspect the installation files ourselves?

Comment: cross-over to SO, you might have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280906/difference-between-groovy-binary-and-source-release/31989849#31989849 or its duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29236736/what-is-the-difference-between-binary-install-and-compile-and-install-from-sourc/29237657#29237657 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26208786/julia-bindeps-difference-between-sources-and-binaries#comment111705430_26208786

Answer (score 5):

From this Ubuntu help page: [InstallingSoftware](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Source_or_Binary.3F):

> **Source packages** are simply packages which just include source code, and can generally be used on any type of machine if the code is compiled in the right way. (For information on how to compile and install source packages, see [CompilingEasyHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo)).
>
> **Binary packages** are ones which have been made specifically for one type of computer, or architecture. Ubuntu supports the x86 (i386 or i686), AMD64 and PPC architectures. The correct binary packages will be used automatically, so you don't have to worry about picking the right ones. To find out which one you are using, open your terminal, type `uname -m` then hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, Source packages need to be compiled by you before installing (they are the code itself) (using make and a compiler).

Binary packages are already compiled for your achitecture and only need to be installed (using dpkg for example)